# Pickling scipy's SuperLU class for incomplete LU factorization

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, pickle

Using [`scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu.html), I compute the incomplete LU-factorization of a very large sparse matrix. As this process is time-consuming I would like to save the computed LU factorization. The function returns a [`scipy.sparse.linalg.SuperLU`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.SuperLU.html) object.

My first attempt was using the pickle module to save the whole object. However, I get a:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'SuperLU'>:
   attribute lookup __builtin__.SuperLU failed
```

error message.

My second idea was saving the relevant class members of the SuperLU object `('L', 'U', 'nnz', 'perm_c', 'perm_r', 'shape')` and then reassemble it. However, the SuperLU object seems to be non-instantiable:

```
>>> SuperLU()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot create 'SuperLU' instances
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can cache the result of my incomplete LU-factorization to a file?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any straightforward way to pickle a `SuperLU` instance. If you could directly instantiate `SuperLU` then you could use [`copy_reg.pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy_reg.html) to register a custom pickling function, but as you've found out, this doesn't seem to be possible. As @MikeMcKerns mentioned, you could save the `L` and `U` sparse triangular matrices, but in order to make use of them you would still need to re-implement `SuperLU.solve()` yourself.

Comment: This does sound like it would be a nice feature to have, so I suggest that you post a new feature request on [the scipy issue tracker](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues)

Comment: Good point @ali_m, I just submitted a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I was following `ali_m`'s advice and wrote my own `solve()` function. After reconstructing the permutation matrices `Pr` and `Pc` I can dump them together with `L` and `R` and have everything I need. I also filled a feature request for `scipy` in the hope that there will be a more straight-forward option in future versions.

Comment: i have the same problem / need to save result of sparse lu factor to disk and revive.. I saw your feature request from 3 yrs ago is still open.  have you found any other way to access the solve function directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find where the `SuperLU` class is actually defined, if could be pickled… unless the `SuperLU` class is defined in **C** -- which is entirely possible.  If the class is defined in **python**, then it can be pickled with the `dill` module.  If it's in **C**, you are out of luck pickling that object directly.

Here's the problem:

```
>>> import dill
>>> import scipy
>>> import scipy.sparse
>>> import scipy.sparse.linalg                       
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2,2],[4,2,0],[2,0,0]])
>>> lu = scipy.sparse.linalg.splu(a)
>>> dill.detect.errors(lu)
PicklingError("Can't pickle <type 'SuperLU'>: it's not found as __builtin__.SuperLU",)
>>> lu
<SuperLU object at 0x106eb0360>
>>> lu.__class__ 
<type 'SuperLU'>
>>> lu.__class__.__module__
'__builtin__'
```

So what do you do?

I'm not sure that this is the full answer, but you can just dump the sparse matrices that make up your `SparseLU` instance.  I might be missing some state, but this should convey the idea…

```
>>> dill.dumps(lu.L)
'\x80\x02cscipy.sparse.csc\ncsc_matrix\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02(U\x06formatq\x03U\x03cscq\x04U\x06_shapeq\x05K\x03K\x03\x86q\x06U\x06indptrq\x07cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x08cnumpy\nndarray\nq\tK\x00\x85q\nU\x01bq\x0b\x87q\x0cRq\r(K\x01K\x04\x85q\x0ecnumpy\ndtype\nq\x0fU\x02i4q\x10K\x00K\x01\x87q\x11Rq\x12(K\x03U\x01<q\x13NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x14b\x89U\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00q\x15tq\x16bU\x07indicesq\x17h\x08h\tK\x00\x85q\x18h\x0b\x87q\x19Rq\x1a(K\x01K\x04\x85q\x1bh\x12\x89U\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00q\x1ctq\x1dbU\x08maxprintq\x1eK2U\x04dataq\x1fh\x08h\tK\x00\x85q h\x0b\x87q!Rq"(K\x01K\x04\x85q#h\x0fU\x02f8q$K\x00K\x01\x87q%Rq&(K\x03U\x01<q\'NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq(b\x89U \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?q)tq*bub.'
>>> dill.dumps(lu.U)
'\x80\x02cscipy.sparse.csc\ncsc_matrix\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02(U\x06formatq\x03U\x03cscq\x04U\x06_shapeq\x05K\x03K\x03\x86q\x06U\x06indptrq\x07cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x08cnumpy\nndarray\nq\tK\x00\x85q\nU\x01bq\x0b\x87q\x0cRq\r(K\x01K\x04\x85q\x0ecnumpy\ndtype\nq\x0fU\x02i4q\x10K\x00K\x01\x87q\x11Rq\x12(K\x03U\x01<q\x13NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x14b\x89U\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00q\x15tq\x16bU\x07indicesq\x17h\x08h\tK\x00\x85q\x18h\x0b\x87q\x19Rq\x1a(K\x01K\x06\x85q\x1bh\x12\x89U\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00q\x1ctq\x1dbU\x08maxprintq\x1eK2U\x04dataq\x1fh\x08h\tK\x00\x85q h\x0b\x87q!Rq"(K\x01K\x06\x85q#h\x0fU\x02f8q$K\x00K\x01\x87q%Rq&(K\x03U\x01<q\'NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq(b\x89U0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0\xbfq)tq*bub.'
```

Obviously, you want to use `dump` instead of `dumps` to pickle to a file.  You might even be able to use numpy's built-in serialization (the pickle is smaller) as well, but I don't know.

Comment: Unfortunately the `SuperLU` class is indeed [implemented purely in C](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superluobject.c), so pickling is a non-starter. As the OP mentioned, `SuperLU` instances also can't be instantiated directly, so there's not much you can do with the lower & upper triangular sparse matrices unless you were to re-implement the `.solve()` method yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a starting point for implementing the `.solve` method... 
it isn't quite right because there is an efficiency warning about using a CSC instead of a CSR matrix during the first `spsolve_triangular` call, but if the `L` matrix will be used multiple times maybe it makes sense to go ahead and convert it before storing it to disk.

```
def spsolve_lu(L, U, b, perm_c=None, perm_r=None):
""" an attempt to use SuperLU data to efficiently solve
    Ax = Pr.T L U Pc.T x = b
     - note that L from SuperLU is in CSC format solving for c
       results in an efficiency warning
    Pr . A . Pc = L . U
    Lc = b      - forward solve for c
     c = Ux     - then back solve for x
"""
if perm_r is not None:
    b_old = b.copy()
    for old_ndx, new_ndx in enumerate(perm_r):
        b[new_ndx] = b_old[old_ndx]
try:    # unit_diagonal is a new kw
    c = spsolve_triangular(L, b, lower=True, unit_diagonal=True)
except TypeError:
    c = spsolve_triangular(L, b, lower=True)
px = spsolve_triangular(U, c, lower=False)
if perm_c is None:
    return px
return px[perm_c]
```